# Why does objcopy remove my section from binary?

Tags: embedded, ld, objcopy

I'm trying to link my tiny bare-metal educational project for ARM. I have one simple assembly source and linker script. There is a special separate section for exception vectors and startup code:

```
.section STARTUP_SECTION, "x"
_reset:
    b reset_handler     @ Reset
    b .                 @ Undefined instruction
    b .                 @ SWI
    b .                 @ Prefetch Abort
    b .                 @ Data Abort
    b .                 @ reserved
    b .                 @ IRQ
    b .                 @ FIQ

reset_handler:
    @ some code here
    b .

@ then .text and .data section
```

And simple linker script:

```
ENTRY(_reset)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0;
    .startup . :
    {
        startup.o (STARTUP_SECTION)
        reset_section_end = .;
    }

    .text. : {*(.text)}
    .data . : {*(.data)}
    .bss  . : {*(.bss COMMON)}

}
```

I see all my sections in the map file produced by linker, and `.text` section lies at higher address than `.startup` as expected. But when I convert it to binary with:

`arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary startup.elf startup.bin`

I see that it starts from `.text` contents, and my startup section is missing. I'm still able to see all sections in the elf file when I disassemble it with objdump, but objcopy removes `.startup`. The section is not marked as NOLOAD or something like this. Is `NOLOAD` type a default for such section and if so, why? And how to mark it as `LOAD` since there is no such section type according to linker manual.

What is going on here?

Comment: Since I'm not near my ARM compiler, I tried with the AVR GCC instead. And guess what, it works for me. Would you mind to extend your example into a [mre], please? [Edit] your question and add also the commands to compile and link, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that a non-standard code section marked with "x" flag is considered by the linker as not "allocatable" by default. "a" flag solves the issue. So, the section declaration finally looks like this:

```
.section STARTUP_SECTION, "xa"
```